# 45 duplicate symbols , Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

[image]my react native app works fine while opening on android but when i try to run for ios it shows error that **45 duplicate symbols  , Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)** [image]

I have modified my podfile deleted and reinstalled pods in my app

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.